# Grabing Page Fragment After Page Loads

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to use load() with a selector

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Documents').load('../searchresults.aspx #listing', '', function() {
        if(status == 'error') {
            $(this).html('Error loading page');
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that the `../searchresults.aspx`  page by itself first display "Loading..." then refreshes with the actual data within a few seconds.

So my div `#Documents` just display "Loading..."

How would I go about getting the `#listing` contents after the pages has completely finishes loading?

Comment: Could you use an iframe?

Comment: sounds like the searchresult page is hitting another url via ajax.  So you should be loading that url instead.  It may or may not be a pain though because ASP use really stupid useless methods for pagination and other tihngs.

Comment: Rooster fiddle doesn't show me another url being called.  Looks more like a postback is being executed.  Vlad is it possible to grab a fragment of the page via an iFrame?  Was thinking about having the iFrame hidden but what to do about the "Loading..."?